# Golang reading from stdin, how to detect special keys (enter, backspace... etc)

Tags: go, stdin, tty, pty

I have the following program that reads user input from stdin:

```
var input string = ""
            exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "cbreak", "min", "1").Run()
            exec.Command("stty", "-F", "/dev/tty", "-echo").Run()
            var b []byte = make([]byte, 1)
            for {
                input += string(b)
            }
```

I want to place some kind of condition inside the for loop so that i can "break" when the user presses "enter" (for example) or remove one char from a string when the user presses (backspace). However, i can't figure out what the byte array or string representation of those two keys are. How do i go about figuring this out ? enter just prints a \w and backspace prins an undefined character.

Comment: On a unix system, the "return" will most probably be `"\n"` and backspace one of `"\b"` or `"\x7f"` in string form.

Comment: Why not use `github.com/nsf/termbox-go` and/or `github.com/jteeuwen/keyboard/termbox` (which makes use of the former)? I have a feeling you picked a rather peculiar approach to solving your task. Instead, you should switch the terminal to the "raw" mode and deal with whatever data it sends to you. `termbox` does the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Consider using http://godoc.org to get an overview of what these packages can do for you (and search for other options).

Comment: Here's [a demo code dealing with keyboard input using `termbox-go`](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go/blob/master/_demos/keyboard.go#L660).

Answer (score 11):

Your use case is explained in this [blog post](https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-get-ascii-code-from-a-key-press-cross-platform-example). Just cross posting the necessary solution from the referenced blog:-

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    term "github.com/nsf/termbox-go"
)

func reset() {
    term.Sync() // cosmestic purpose
}

func main() {
    err := term.Init()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer term.Close()

    fmt.Println("Enter any key to see their ASCII code or press ESC button to quit")

keyPressListenerLoop:
    for {
        switch ev := term.PollEvent(); ev.Type {
        case term.EventKey:
            switch ev.Key {
            case term.KeyEsc:
                break keyPressListenerLoop
            case term.KeyF1:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("F1 pressed")
            case term.KeyF2:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("F2 pressed")
            case term.KeyF3:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("F3 pressed")
            case term.KeyF4:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("F4 pressed")
            case term.KeyF5:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("F5 pressed")
            case term.KeyF6:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("F6 pressed")
            case term.KeyF7:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("F7 pressed")
            case term.KeyF8:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("F8 pressed")
            case term.KeyF9:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("F9 pressed")
            case term.KeyF10:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("F10 pressed")
            case term.KeyF11:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("F11 pressed")
            case term.KeyF12:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("F12 pressed")
            case term.KeyInsert:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("Insert pressed")
            case term.KeyDelete:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("Delete pressed")
            case term.KeyHome:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("Home pressed")
            case term.KeyEnd:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("End pressed")
            case term.KeyPgup:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("Page Up pressed")
            case term.KeyPgdn:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("Page Down pressed")
            case term.KeyArrowUp:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("Arrow Up pressed")
            case term.KeyArrowDown:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("Arrow Down pressed")
            case term.KeyArrowLeft:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("Arrow Left pressed")
            case term.KeyArrowRight:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("Arrow Right pressed")
            case term.KeySpace:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("Space pressed")
            case term.KeyBackspace:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("Backspace pressed")
            case term.KeyEnter:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("Enter pressed")
            case term.KeyTab:
                reset()
                fmt.Println("Tab pressed")

            default:
                // we only want to read a single character or one key pressed event
                reset()
                fmt.Println("ASCII : ", ev.Ch)

            }
        case term.EventError:
            panic(ev.Err)
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Output

```
Enter any key to see their ASCII code or press ESC button to quit
Tab pressed
ASCII : 49
ASCII : 50
ASCII : 51
ASCII : 52
ASCII : 53
F1 pressed
Arrow Up pressed
Arrow Left pressed
Arrow Down pressed
Arrow Right pressed
Arrow Up pressed
```

If you don't mind hitting the Enter button then the above code looks like below:-

```
package main

 import (
         "fmt"
         "os"
         "bufio"
 )



 func main() {

         fmt.Println("Press ESC button or Ctrl-C to exit this program")
         fmt.Println("Press any key to see their ASCII code follow by Enter")

         for {
                 // only read single characters, the rest will be ignored!!
                 consoleReader := bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin, 1)
                 fmt.Print(">")
                 input, _ := consoleReader.ReadByte()

                 ascii := input

                 // ESC = 27 and Ctrl-C = 3
                 if ascii == 27 || ascii == 3 {
                         fmt.Println("Exiting...")
                         os.Exit(0)
                 }

                 fmt.Println("ASCII : ", ascii)
         }

 }
```