# References for keyboard input parsing algorithm?

Tags: linux, go, keyboard, keyboard-events

I am working on software for an embedded system where I need to parse the values of a USB device which is recognized by the Linux OS as a keyboard. The issue is that I need to convert the various keyboard events to actual text.

To me this seems like a fairly common task that should exist out there somewhere. Is there any projects or references that explain a good algorithm for implementing this? Stuff like when modifier keys are pressed, what the values become and stuff like that.

If it matters I am using Golang but implementations or references in other languages would be fine too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang reading from stdin, how to detect special keys (enter, backspace... etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159137/golang-reading-from-stdin-how-to-detect-special-keys-enter-backspace-etc)

Answer (score 0):

I think this tool can solve your problem: [termbox](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go)