# How to detect if a key was pressed by user and continue

Tags: go

I am new to Go, and wanted to display a text to the user and wait for the user to press any key. As soon as the user presses a key, it should proceed to the next line of code else it should stay there. How do we achieve that in Go?

Let's say the text is: "Press any key to proceed..."
and I display as:

```
fmt.Printf(Press any key to proceed...")
```

After this how do I detect whether a key was pressed in order to continue?

Comment: What OS are you trying to run on?

Comment: I use both Windows and Linux

Comment: If you are dead set on using ANY key, check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159137/golang-reading-from-stdin-how-to-detect-special-keys-enter-backspace-etc