# How can I get keyboard input data in Go?

Tags: linux, go, terminal, keyboard, raw

I want to be able to tell if a user presses things like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+[something] or <kbd>Esc</kbd> on their keyboard in Go. The program runs in a Linux environment inside a terminal.

Answer (score 5):

1. If you just want to simply read the string or bytes, you can do this

```golang
in := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
data := in.Bytes()
```

2. If you want to capture the system semaphore, you can get it by registering the semaphore monitor

```golang
signal.Notify(os.Interrupt, os.Kill) // os.Interrupt=0x2 os.Kill=0x9
```

3. Get ASCII code from a key press(cross-platform) (use github.com/nsf/termbox-go)

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    term "github.com/nsf/termbox-go"
)

func main() {
    err := term.Init()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer term.Close()

    for {
        switch ev := term.PollEvent(); ev.Type {
        case term.EventKey:
            switch ev.Key {
            case term.KeyEsc:
                term.Sync()
                fmt.Println("ESC pressed")
            case term.KeyF1:
                term.Sync()
                fmt.Println("F1 pressed")
            case term.KeyInsert:
                term.Sync()
                fmt.Println("Insert pressed")
            case term.KeyDelete:
                term.Sync()
                fmt.Println("Delete pressed")
            case term.KeyHome:
                term.Sync()
                fmt.Println("Home pressed")
            case term.KeyEnd:
                term.Sync()
                fmt.Println("End pressed")
            case term.KeyPgup:
                term.Sync()
            case term.KeyArrowRight:
                term.Sync()
                fmt.Println("Arrow Right pressed")
            case term.KeySpace:
                term.Sync()
                fmt.Println("Space pressed")
            case term.KeyBackspace:
                term.Sync()
                fmt.Println("Backspace pressed")
            case term.KeyEnter:
                term.Sync()
                fmt.Println("Enter pressed")
            case term.KeyTab:
                term.Sync()
                fmt.Println("Tab pressed")

            default:
                term.Sync()
                fmt.Println("ASCII : ", ev.Ch)

            }
        case term.EventError:
            panic(ev.Err)
        }
    }
}
```

4. Read single characters

```golang
consoleReader := bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin, 1)
input, _ := consoleReader.ReadByte()
ascii := input

// ESC = 27 and Ctrl-C = 3
if ascii == 27 || ascii == 3 {
    fmt.Println("Exiting...")
    os.Exit(0)
}

fmt.Println("ASCII : ", ascii)
```

> [Golang reading from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159137/golang-reading-from-stdin-how-to-detect-special-keys-enter-backspace-etc)
> [Get ASCII code from a key press](https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-get-ascii-code-from-a-key-press-cross-platform-example)